# pandas DataFrame groupby fillna inplace

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, missing-data

Could you, please, let me know how I can fill missing values in place in a pandas DataFrame groupby? Somehow, when I fill them not in place, it works, but giving `inplace=True` does not change the input DataFrame. An example code is below:

```py
import pandas as pd
t = pd.DataFrame(data={'i0':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                       'i1':[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3],
                       'i2':['A']*12,
                       'x':[10.,20.,30.,np.nan,np.nan,21.,
                            np.nan,41.,np.nan,np.nan,32.,42.]})
t.set_index(['i0','i1','i2'], inplace=True)
t.sort_index(inplace=True)

# works
t = t.groupby(level='i1').fillna(method='ffill')

# does not work
t.groupby(level='i1').fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do not chain inplace with groupby which will yeild the unsung error

Comment: @WeNYoBen I do not get any error, but the input DataFrame remains unchanged. Is the `inplace` argument in [groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.fillna.html) not implemented yet?

Comment: I think the document is off . Will report in Github